# Trying to access linux server via http -getting a password prompt

Tags: linux, debian, webserver, wordpress

I'm trying to do a Wordpress installation via ssh on a virtual machine running Debian Wheezy.

I can connect to the server just fine using PuTTY but I'm not sure what I should do when it's time to start the browser installation part of the Wordpress installation, because when I enter the IP address of the server in a browser, I get a username/password prompt. I can't figure out what this password could be. I have root access to the Debian installation, so can I perhaps change this password somewhere with my root priviledges? I'm not running any control panel like plesk or cPanel.

To ask it in a shorter way, where in Debian can I control the password prompt that opens when I try to access the server via http (port 80)?

Comment: Check if there's a ".htaccess"-File in the Webdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! When I use MC to go to /var/www I see only one file, index.html. The file .htaccess is a hidden file right? Do you know if MC hides hidden files from view?

Answer (score 0):

building on the previous comments (my rep's too low; can't comment yet)...

sounds like a hidden .htaccess and .htpasswd files.

If you're on the command line you can run the following to quickly locate the files.

```
$ cd [your (htdocs|www) folder]
$ find . -name ".htaccess"
$ find . -name ".htpasswd"
```

If you're using MC, you can expose hidden files by:

```
Menu bar -> Options -> Panel Options -> Main Panel Options
[x] Show hidden files
```

I have no idea how to do the equivalent to 'find' in mc.

If .htaccess exists, and has an *AuthUserFile* clause pointing to an .htpasswd file, may be the issue. Try commenting out the AuthUserFile line (put a # in the beginning of the line).

--- Note: I previously advised moving/deleting/renaming the htaccess file; but Wordpress may need it for permalinks, so blowing it away, especially in the wordpress folder may not be your best option.